# Detect automatically the escape sequence for a key combination

Tags: shell, terminal, kernel, key-bindings

Is it possible to automatically detect the escape sequence for a key combination?

, i.e., instead of running `cat` followed by pressing `ctrl+right` or `ctrl+left` manually to detect the escape sequence as `^[[5C` or `^[[5D` respectively, can it be automated? In that case, we may be able to send fn(`ctrl+left`) or fn(`ctrl+right`) as input to cat via pipe and get the output(for the first time, when `^[[5C` or `^[[5D` are unknown) directly.

```
fn(char a[]='ctrl+right') {..outputs the actual keypress signal for the input string a.. ;} | cat; fn=?
```

This question is the exact reverse of my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547008/reverse-map-the-keys-binding-value-to-the-key-combination.

I am asking this to automate the process of setting up key-bindings in the terminals, for devs, so that they need not run manually for all possible combinations, as we had to do now ([as seen here](https://superuser.com/a/807210/364519))

Comment: I don't understand the question. `cat` is how you find out the escape sequence for a keypress. Are you asking how to turn the *words* `ctrl+right` into the appropriate key sequence?

Comment: Yup. Instead of manually pressing ctrl+left into the keyboard, is there any way that i can send it programmatically. if possible, is it also possible for all combinations of the keys

Comment: What's the point here? And isn't that exactly what the terminfo option in the documentation does?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to automatically detect the escape sequence for a key
>   combination?

Since the shell (as any user program) has no insight into the terminal driver, it cannot predict what the driver will do with a key combination. Consider also that with certain terminals we can change the keyboard's behavior (e. g. cf. [`xmodmap`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.9.0/doc/html/xmodmap.1.html)). Automatic detection is not universally possible.